# What is wrong in this grep command?

Tags: linux, perl, grep

Okay... so I'm trying to make a dictionary using *Crunch* and *Grep* I've also tried using *Perl* instead.

```
crunch 8 12 1234567890 -d 2@ | grep -v '\([0-9]\) .*\1.*\1.*\1.*' | grep 41106041
```

So, basically i want to filter all passwords which numbers appear 3 times

```
grep 41106041
```

Is just to test if the code works.. and it doesn't.

I've also tried some "C style" perl code as I'm still a newbie to perl:

```
#! /bin/perl
@lines=<STDIN>;
$c=0;
foreach $number(@lines)
{
    $acum=undef;
    $pos=0;
    while($pos <= &countdig($number))
    {
        if ($acum=$digit)
        {
            $c=$c+1;
        }
        else
        {
            $c=0;
        }
        $acum=$digit;

    }
    if ($c=3)
    {
        print "$number"." ";
    }
    $c=0;
}

sub countdig
{
    my($j)=0;
    chomp(my(@n)=@_);
    print "first dig $n[$j] \n";
    while($_[0][$j]>=0 && $_[0][j]<=9)
    {
        $j+=1;

    }
    print "j total : $j  \n";

    $j;
}
```

Countdig is supposed to count the number of digits but thing is.. I can't access a scalar variable as a list.. so well if you guys could explain me how to make it work it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `grep` is failing because there is a stray space in your pattern, and you are searching for 4 identical digits (the one captured, plus three more by backreference).

```
$ printf '12345678\n41106041\n87654321\n' | grep -v '\(.\).*\1.*\1'
12345678
87654321
```

---

The problem is not being a newbie to Perl, cause it's easy to turn a C solution

```
// For each line

char *num = ...;

int digits[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
   digits[i] = 0;
}

const char *p = num;
int triple = 0;
for (; *p && *p != '\n'; ++p) {
   if (++digits[*p - '0'] == 3) {
      triple = 1;
      break;
   }
}

if (triple) {
   ...
}
```

into a Perl solution

```
while (my $num = <>) {
   chomp($num);

   my @digits;
   my $triple;
   for my $digit (split //, $num) {
      if (++$digits[$digit] == 3) {
         $triple = 1;
         last;
      }
   }

   say $num if $triple;
}
```

Of course, a Perl programmer might very well use the same approach you used for `grep`.

```
while (<>) {
   if (!/(.).*\1.*\1/) {
      print;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is also a space after the first digit in the OP's attempt.

Comment: Making a solution in c wasn't quite the problem but thanks anyway. I tested out the script in perl versus grep and it seems perl handles bruteforce data way more effectively. Thanks again for answering such a silly question, it helped me a lot.

Comment: It's efficient because it's *not* brute force. It does at most `length($num)` checks. The regexp is actually the brute force approach, performing numerous checks

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 41106041 | grep -v '\([0-9]\).*\1.*\1.*
```